# Why WebKit using Cairo is very slow on windows?

Tags: webkit, cairo

I compiled WebKit based on WinCairo on windows. The built executable is quite slow in rendering. I built it using the following command line

`perl WebKit/Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --wincairo --release --no-experimental-features --cmakeargs="-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-cl -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang-cl"`

Why resulting executable is slow in rendering? If I select a paragraph on a website then delay is easily felt.

Is it expected to be slow?

Comment: Could you tell me your detailed testing procedure? Which page are you using? It sounds like you are measuring text layout performance. WinCairo is using Uniscribe in Source/WebCore/platform/graphics/win/UniscribeController.cpp, which is rather slower.  Did you take benchmark results? For example, MotionMark1.1.

Comment: I uploaded my benchmark results: https://fujii.github.io/2019/07/05/webkit-on-windows/

Comment: I launched minibrowser application, it opens webkit.org by default, any text block selection on this page is slow. it is easily noticeable. It appears that WinCairo port is not using GPU or Hardware acceleration?? for rendering.

Comment: I confirmed the issue with WinCairo WK2 (non-AC), AppleWin without AC and Otter browser. But I don't see the issue with WinCairo WK1 (AC), AppleWin (AC). This issue happens only in non-AC mode. This page is very heavy for non-AC because there is a rotating compass which is a large SVG and radial-gradient is also used.

Comment: Thanks @fujii for your analysis. I have moved on to CEF3. it performs better.